# How to convert PDF to Microsoft Power Point in Salesforce?

Tags: community, appexchange, pdf

Actually my original issue is generating Microsoft Power Point but I could not find it in Salesforce, I found third party such but I always get frustrated into the limitation such some complex queries ,images limitation etc.

So I need to move on and find other alternative.It seem generating PDF much better than generating powerpoint.Example I generate PDF in Salesforce document, then I want to convert it into Power Point. so is there any tool in Salesforce that we can converting PDF to PPTX?

Or any tool that advance in generating PPTX in Salesforce?

Comment: you can use conga composer to generate PPT from SFDC. In Composer, you define a PPT template and then it is populated by values from your object.

Comment: I am using conga currently but it does not support my business requirement.It support well in Word but unfortunately not
in Power Point.Example:I need more tablestart in one slide.The image will converted into background cell .The image only supported for tablestart not Nth Row.Not support Matrix Report and complex query .So I need to find other alternatives for PPTX.I need tool or alternative that I can use controller to populate data maybe into XML or something but that tool is flexible enough for me to manipulate the data.

Comment: have you tried Conga Support - they are great

Comment: Yes,I already communicate with them,they are great.But  I figured out it not able to support my business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Works well in Office 2007):

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" contentType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint/#test.ppt">
```

Other tool that you can use is "Adobe Acrobat XI Pro”. Costs around $15-20 and works great with conversion of PDF to PPT.

Comment: How you generate the slide in the code above?Are you using controller to populate table and layout manually?